# BootUpReceiver crash

Tags: android, service

I have an app that is starting up from boot. But it's crashing. When I start it up from a button the service just work. I have all the permissons..

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".StartUpService" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.my.app.StartUpReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.my.app.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BootReceiver:

```
package com.my.app;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, StartUpReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.cancel(pi);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5*60*1000, pi);
    }
}
```

StartUpReceiver:

```
package com.my.app;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class StartUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, StartUpService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

StartUpService:

```
package com.my.app;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StartUpService extends Service {   
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) { 

        String preferences = "SERVICE";

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(preferences, 0);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstrun", false);
        editor.commit();

        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        CookieManager cookie_manager = CookieManager.getInstance();

        String cookies = cookie_manager.getCookie("myurl");
        if(cookies != null) {
            int index = cookies.indexOf("sessiecode");
            if(index != -1) {
                String[] cookie = cookies.split("sessiecode=");
                String c = cookie[cookie.length - 1]; 
                new GetInteger().execute("myurl");
            }
        }


    }

    class GetInteger extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;  

                HttpGet post = new HttpGet(uri[0]);

                response = httpclient.execute(post);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){                 
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    String responseString = out.toString();
                    return responseString;
                } else { 
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    Log.e("com.my.app", "HTTPRequest error");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("com.my.app", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            */
            return "5"; 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            int responseInt = Integer.parseInt(result);
            int NOTIF_ID = 1234;  
            NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
            notifManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
            if(responseInt > 0) {

                Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_note, "Nieuw privébericht", System.currentTimeMillis());  
                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(One2xsService.this, 0, new Intent(StartUpService.this, MainActivity.class), 0); 

                String noteString;
                if(responseInt > 1) {
                    noteString = "Je hebt " + responseInt + " ongelezen berichten";
                } else {
                    noteString = "Je hebt 1 ongelezen bericht";                     
                }

                note.setLatestEventInfo(One2xsService.this, "Nieuw privébericht", noteString, pintent);  
                note.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notifManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, note); 

                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(200);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I hope anyone can help!

Edit, Log:

```
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.my.app.StartUpService@40518b30 with Intent { cmp=com.my.app/.StartUpService }: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CookieSyncManager::createInstance() needs to be called before CookieSyncManager::getInstance()
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2052)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:994)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CookieSyncManager::createInstance() needs to be called before CookieSyncManager::getInstance()
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.getInstance(CookieSyncManager.java:81)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.blay.one2xs.One2xsService.onStart(One2xsService.java:56)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:428)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2039)
02-02 19:00:27.100: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: you forget to add log when application is crashing with question. plz add it

Comment: Ow wait, I will add them. One moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in log :

> CookieSyncManager::createInstance() needs to be called before
>   CookieSyncManager::getInstance()

you will need to call createInstance() before calling getInstance() method as :

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getApplicationContext); 
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
CookieManager cookie_manager = CookieManager.getInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm so sorry I didn't see it.